# Create a Symmetric Matrix from a vector in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, vector, symmetric

How to covert vector A to symmetric matrix M in MATLAB

[image]

[image]

Such that M is a symmetric matrix (i.e. A21=A12) and all diagonal terms are equal (i.e. A11=A22=A33=A44).

Comment: We don't support LaTeX here. Please use coding syntax.  In addition, I can't see how to go from `A` to `M`.  What is the general rule of construction?  What happens when you extend this beyond 4 elements in the vector?

Comment: Please see the revised question

Comment: That's better. Thanks.  I'm reopening as this isn't a duplicate of using `toeplitz`.

Comment: where is the A31, A13 element? or A24, A42?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`hankel`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/matlab/ref/hankel.html) to help you create the symmetric matrix, then when you're finished, set the diagonal entries of this intermediate result to be the first element of the vector in `A`:

```
M = hankel(A,A(end:-1:1));
M(eye(numel(A))==1) = A(1);
```

## Example

```
>> A = [1;2;3;4]

A =

     1
     2
     3
     4

>> M = hankel(A,A(end:-1:1));
>> M(eye(numel(A))==1) = A(1)

M =

     1     2     3     4
     2     1     4     3
     3     4     1     2
     4     3     2     1
```

As you can see, `M(i,j) = M(j,i)` except for the diagonal, where each element is equal to `A(1)`.